# Failed to load 'endpoint': Request header field If-Modified-Since is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response

Tags: node.js, mongodb, api, express, mean-stack

I have created one API service using nodejs and it is working fine when I accessing through the browser. But when I'm try to call it from web application (MEAN app), getting the ***"Failed to load http://localhost:2020/api/posts: Request header field If-Modified-Since is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response"*** issue.

Following code is added in index.js of the API service.

```
    // Add headers
    app.use(function (req, res, next) {

    // Website you wish to allow to connect
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');

    // Request methods you wish to allow
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');

    // Request headers you wish to allow
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');

    // Set to true if you need the website to include cookies in the requests sent
    // to the API (e.g. in case you use sessions)
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);

    // Pass to next layer of middleware
    next();
});
```

and added following lines in controller of the web app,

```
app.config(["$routeProvider", "$httpProvider", function ($routeProvider, $httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = '*';
}
]);
```

But no luck for added the above lines. How to resolve this issue ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to add `If-Modified-Since` to `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` in your server code:

```
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type,If-Modified-Since');
```

Also the part where you touch HTTP header on client seems useless to me, I don't think you can do anything with that.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have applied your answer and got another error **Request header field Access-Control-Allow-Headers is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response**. 
And I solved that issue by removing the following line from controller of web app, **$httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = '*';**. Now its working fine and get called the service and received the response successfully.